# DSE Gremlin schema Error after Upgradation ( Datastax 5.0 to 5.1)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

After Upgrading Datastax Cassandra from version 5.0 to 5.1, we are getting
gremlin error while connecting to the existing keyspace as mentioned below, While there is no issue in creating new keyspace in graph and connecting through gremlin.

```
$gremlin> :remote config alias g chat_bot.g
==>g=chat_bot.g
$gremlin> schema
```

1) Error injecting constructor,

```
com.datastax.bdp.gcore.datastore.DataStoreException: Failed to execute statement
  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl.<init>(DseGraphImpl.java:159)
  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphFactoryImpl$$Lambda$760/154747472 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule)
  while locating com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl

1 error
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:172)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:424)
```

**tail /var/log/cassandra/system.log**

```
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140) [netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2017-05-10 12:21:34,818  ReadCommand.java:532 - Read 9 live rows and 4881 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM cordiant_chat.chat_onlineusers_status WHERE org_id = 2 LIMIT 5000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
WARN  [ReadStage-1] 2017-05-10 12:21:34,837  ReadCommand.java:532 - Read 9 live rows and 4881 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM cordiant_chat.chat_onlineusers_status WHERE org_id = 2 LIMIT 5000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
root@ip-10-10-1-36:~#

nobody to help??

Comment: have you tried `schema.describe()` ?

Comment: Yes.same error.

Comment: Can you detail the exact upgrade procedure you used or followed? Also do you see any errors in the nodes `<Logs home>/system.log`

Comment: We have done the below mentioned step one by one in 3 nodes....

nodetool flush 
nodetool upgradesstables
java -version
nodetool drain
/etc/init.d/dse stop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dse-full
/etc/init.d/dse start
nodetool upgradesstables

Comment: tail /var/log/cassandra/system.log has the output

Comment: Ok the upgrade procedure sounds ok, for ref the docs are here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE51.html It probably would be useful to see the whole log from the node, if you could share it somewhere?

Comment: You can see full cassandra system log through this link https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AApSOmFHvv0ycpk&v=TextFileEditor&id=B14A54039F6CDF96%21108&cid=B14A54039F6CDF96&parId=root

Comment: sorry for the delay, I had a look at it appears you're missing a system table, have a look at this gist here since my answer is too big for a comment and not complete enough for a SO answer ... yet: https://gist.github.com/markcurtis1970/d1839bd6a9425d440a91bf8394a63207

Comment: U r right Markc that file is missing.Do you have any clue about how it was happend(since we just upgraded datastax) and how can i recover it back.

Comment: Can you list the output of `show tables` please? As you can see from my gist you normally have 3 keyspaces per graph.

Comment: cqlsh:chat_bot_system> desc tables;

shared_data  dseg_variables

cqlsh:chat_bot_system>

Comment: cqlsh:chat_bot> desc TABLEs;

id_allocation  v_user_p  v_transcript_p  v_user_e  v_transcript_e

cqlsh:chat_bot>

Comment: cqlsh:chat_bot_pvt> desc TABLEs;

<empty>

Comment: Would you mind putting that into a github gist or pastebin, its a bit confusing to read?

Comment: please check this-        https://gist.github.com/nithinbalantpm

Comment: Ok thats a bit odd - you should never be missing tables under the  `chat_bot_system` keyspace. The only explanation I can think of here is they were dropped from a `cqlsh` client.